# configure ".cer" certificate in Postman

Tags: ssl, certificate, postman

Trying to execute a POST **https** request in **Postman**, in vain.

I did turn on the SSL verification "on". Also, I configured my *.cer file under settings>certificate tab. But... Am I missing any thing ?

I am getting following error.

The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General